# How to get first occurrence of the element from multiple match found in testcafe

Tags: xpath, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

There are cases where I can see multiple node matches found if I evaluate my Selenium xpath/locator.

Example: //span[@username='xyz'] ( sample code using Selenium )

if the above relative path matches with multiple nodes (ex: 5 matching nodes found. Find the list of matching nodes below ).

In selenium I can use like: (//span[@username='xyz'])[1] which accessing first match out of 5 matches found.

How we can achieve the same using TestCafe?

Answer (score 5):

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `fixture`
    .page('https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/');

const elementByXPath = Selector(xpath => {
    const iterator = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null )
    const items = [];

    let item = iterator.iterateNext();

    while (item) {
        items.push(item);
        item = iterator.iterateNext();
    }

    return items;
});

test('Click by first checkbox', async t => {
    const firstCheckboxSelector = Selector(elementByXPath('//input[@type="checkbox"]'));
    const secondCheckboxSelector = Selector(elementByXPath('//input[@type="checkbox"]')).nth(1);
    
    await t.click(firstCheckboxSelector);
});
```

See also: [Use XPath Selectors](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/use-xpath-selectors)

Comment: Thanks @mlosev , I have used nth() method to mentioned my node index and its worked to me :).  but could you please help me to understand why you created Const elementbyXpath.

Comment: TestCafe doesn't support XPath selectors as a 'Selector' argument. This is why I've created a utility function for this. 
Also, you can track [this] (https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1178) issue in the TestCafe repository to know when XPath support will be implemented.

Comment: cool, we can use xpath in Testcafe using your utility, thank you very much @mlosev :)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using the inbuilt function on Selector much easily.

```
 let locator = Selector('span').withAttribute('username','xyz');
 await t.click(locator.nth(0));
```